# Using day and time to get dates for the rest of the year

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I'm trying to build an online version of a roster as a side project. I'm using FullCalendar to help me display this and have this functioning well with dummy data.

For each staff member, I know the day that they work and the start/finish time.

I'm looking for a way to initially seed my database with dates and times this person will work so that I can pull these in to FullCalendar later on.

I've been using Carbon for my dates and using `new Carbon('next Monday 18:00:00')` has been working for me, however extending this past the next Monday would then require adding `->addDays(7)`.

Using that to generate dates for given days for the rest of the year seems messy and not very streamlined.

I stumbled across the use of `CarbonInterval`, which could be used like so `CarbonInterval::week()`. However, I'm not fluent with Carbon and not really sure how to implement it.

Currently, the data I have is like this for each staff member:

```
'staff_id' => 1,
'day' => 'Monday',
'start_time' => '18:00:00',
'finish_time' => '22:00:00',
```

I am looking for a way to use this to generate fields like this in a a different table for the rest of this year:

```
'staff_id' => 1,
'date' => '2015-1-25',
'start_time' => '18:00:00',
'finish_time' => '22:00:00',
```

How could I do this simply?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. But maybe you can try for example: `Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d)` it will return you a date with specify format

Comment: @SSuhat I am wanting to seed my database with all the shifts that will occur over the next year with the date of that shift by providing the day that the shift occurs on. Through Carbon you can generate a date for next week by using `new Carbon('next Monday')` and this would return a date for the next Monday. I am looking for a way to do this to return dates for all of the Monday's so that I can easily seed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$date = new Carbon('next Monday 18:00:00');
while($date->format('Y') == 2016)
{
    //insert statement or push on array
    $date->addWeek();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, always so simple yet just outside of your grasp. With a little modification this did exactly what I needed!